# Highcharts markers on legend and hover ONLY

Tags: highcharts, legend, series, markers

I need to show highchart markers only on hover state and in the legend at all times. I don't want it to show on normal state in the chart. I searched for this and found this post which did not work for me

[Series markers disable on lines and enable on legend in Highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889593/series-markers-disable-on-lines-and-enable-on-legend-in-highchart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset drawPoints function.

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawPoints = function() { };
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/11pLzk9m/1/