# Highcharts not zooming series using option Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawPoints = function() { }

Tags: hover, highcharts, zooming, markers

I am creating a graph where I want to show the markers of the series only when hovering. I already tried the solution as shown on this question ([Highcharts markers on legend and hover ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997776/highcharts-markers-on-legend-and-hover-only/32006014)), and it works perfectly to show the markers when I want to. 
    However, I have another graph in the same html page that needs to show the markers and when I applied the solution presented on that question on the graph that I want (first graph) and I zoom at the other graph (second graph) the series that are represented by dots does not zoom, they keep all the markers on the graph. 
The option

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawPoints = function() { };
```

is on line 37 of the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/erifel/sx3dcmny/

Comment: You should be able to use marker.enabled: false with series.states.hover.lineWidthPlus: 0 for achieving your chart without reseting drawPoints function: https://jsfiddle.net/sx3dcmny/11/ this will give you a possibility to zoom in you chart. If this example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thanks for your reply. Doing what you suggested works perfectly for the zoom, but the legend of the first graph does not show the markers of the series that are visible only when hovering. Any suggestion to show the markers symbols on the legend?

Comment: You can wrap renderItem function in your Legend.proto https://jsfiddle.net/sx3dcmny/12/ Does this example meet your requirements?

Comment: It works perfectly @GrzegorzBlachliński. Thank you very much. You can add this as the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use **marker.enabled: false** and **series.states.hover.lineWidthPlus: 0** for achieving your chart without reseting drawPoints function. This will give you a possibility to redraw your markers when zooming on you chart.

If you want to show hidden markers in your legend, you can wrap renderItem function in your Legend prototype:

```
H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype,'renderItem',function(proceed,item){
  var enabled = item.options.marker.enabled;
  item.options.marker.enabled = true;
  proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  item.options.marker.enabled = enabled;
});
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: https://jsfiddle.net/sx3dcmny/12/